# 1st degree equation rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why do we either add or subtract the same number infront of the equal sign?

Example:

$x+9=14$

With rule one applied:

$x+9+3=14+3$

But why should you do this in order to solve a relatively easy equation like $x+9=14$?

Comment: How else would you solve the equation?

Comment: @5xum by $14-9=x$?

Comment: And how do you know that $14-9=x$?

Comment: Why don't you substract $9$ instead of add $3$?

Comment: @yokihadu Can you explain **exactly** what you would do? Make a step by step explanation, and justify each step.

Comment: @5xum Well I'd try to discover what would fit $x$. The most logical way (IMHO) to do so would be to take $14$ and subtract $9$ from it in order to know what $x$ is.

Comment: @yokihadu But how do you know that subtracting $9$ from $14$ will result in $x$?

Comment: @5xum Well, because if you'd reverse it (so we have $14-9=5$ where $x=5$) we get $5+9=14$ which makes the equation correct, right?

Comment: @yokihadu Sure, $5$ is the solution, but saying "I make this step because it gives me $5$ and I know $5$ is the solution" is a pretty bad argument. You just sort of "guessed" the solution. But if you **add** $-9$ to both sides of the equation, you get an equivalent equation $x=5$, which immediatelly tells you what the solution is!

Comment: @5xum Okay, that makes sense. So basically these rules are applied to prove your answer?

Comment: @yokihadu You could say so, yes.  They provide a theoretical groundwork through which you can prove that subtracting $9$ from $14$ will actually result in $x$.

Comment: I really don't understand where is the question. "But why should you do this in order to solve a relatively easy equation like $x+9=14$?" Who told you that you should do this?? If you find this equation is relatively easy then what is your question? "With rule one applied: x+9+3=14+3" Why would one want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

You would say that it is very obvious that the solution is

$$x=14-9=5,$$

but why do you think you are allowed to just move the $9$ to the other side with a minus sign? Well, you are correct, you can do this. But the justification needs your first rule. Actually you do the following:

\begin{align}
x+9&=14&&|\;-\!9\text{ on both sides}\\
x+\color{red}{9-9}&=14-9 &&|\;\color{red}{9-9}=0 \\
x + 0&= 14-9 \\
x &=5.
\end{align}

But as you learned that this is a very long way to do a very easy thing, you just drop the intermediate steps and directly write the $9$ to the other side.

Answer (score 2):

It´s a way to isolate the x that in the case of equations of degree 1 works very mechanically. Basically, to do it formally, I guess that you shall find a solution and prove that it´s unique. Well it´s proved that an equation of degree 1 has an unique solution on $\mathbb{C}$ so you just have to find the solution in the way you want. You can do it even trying.

Answer (score 2):

The question of yours that *why* we are adding or subtracting same number on the both sides of an equation is answered by considering the fact that we have to find the value of *x* which *satisfies* the equation. Therefore, we employ a *trick* to isolate *x* on one side of equation.

The question that *how* this act of adding or subtracting is *justified* needs a proof which you can easily construct yourself. If you face any problems, post them here.

The only thing which I will advice you is to use the truth of *axioms* to construct your proof. These *axioms* may be of real number system if you take them as undefined object or if you take, for example positive integers as undefined objects, then use validity of *theorems* related to real numbers deduced from *axioms* to construct a proof.

Answer (score 1):

You would do so that $x$ is the only term on the left hand side.

Solving an equation means getting the term you want to solve for (e.g $x$) on its own on one side of the equation.

If you have an equation of the form $x+a=b$, then to get $x$ on its own, you need to subtract $a$ from both sides. Subtracting any other number that is not equal to $a$, will not make $x$ the only term on the left hand side